# Why does sourcing my workspace cause the error "catkin_make: command not found"?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, qtcreator, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been messing around with my catkin workspace in an attempt to get QtCreator working with ROS (Indigo Igloo, Ubuntu 14.04, QtCreator 5.9.1), and somewhere along the way I've messed up something important. So now, if I run:

```
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
$ cd repo/workspace/
$ catkin_make
```

Everything builds properly, but if I source my workspace between sourcing the ROS distro and running `catkin_make` then the command fails. I.e. if I run:

```
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
$ source /home/user/repo/workspace/devel/setup.bash
$ cd repo/workspace/
$ catkin_make
```

Then I get the following error

```
catkin_make: command not found
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? Obviously, there is something wrong with my setup but I don't understand enough about CMake to figure it out. I'm also not sure what diagnostic info I need to post here to help others, so if there is something specific about my setup that I should post here, let me know. Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

---

#### Updates

As per @psammut's comments, I tried copying all the source code into a new workspace. I can run `catkin_make` in the new workspace just fine, regardless of whether it is sourced or not. But the minute I source my original workspace, `catkin_make` throws an error in *either* workspace.

As per @ahendrix's answer. If I build my workspace with Qt (or try to since it fails when Qt tries) and the Qt `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is set to "/home/user/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64", my `PATH` variable looks like this before and after sourcing the workspace:

Before:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/home/user/.nvm/versions/...
```

After:

```
/home/user/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin:/home/user/.nvm/versions/...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271505/why-does-sourcing-my-workspace-cause-the-error-%22catkin_make:-command-not-found%22?/) by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2327 on 2017-09-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2017-09-25**:
Hate to be that guy, but if you installed ros from the binaries, have you tried just uninstalling and re-installing?

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2017-09-25**:
Also, another suggestion, if you didn't touch the ros files and re-installing is not the cause of the problem, simply make a new workspace and just transfer over the source files to it. Then rebuild and try again.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-09-25**:
No worries, re-installing is definitely an option (done it before). But I'd like to leave it as a last resort, if only because I'll (hopefully) learn something if I can solve the underlying problem. I'll try your suggestion of a new workspace and report back.

**Comment by [DrewHamilton](https://answers.ros.org/users/64242/drewhamilton/) on 2020-12-19**:
So... HOW IN THE WORLD DO WE PROPERLY SET UP QT 5 LIBS!?!?!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-20**:
@DrewHamilton You should create a new question and reference this one. That'll give your issue more visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like your workspace is setting the PATH environment variable incorrectly. Sourcing one workspace overrides and previous workspace or other setup.bash, so it doesn't matter if you've sourced the setup.bash for the system install of ROS or not.

I would look at the PATH after you've sourced the setup.bash for your workspace, to see if it's including a path to a previous version of ROS or a workspace that's been deleted.

You can re-create the setup.bash in your workspace by deleting the devel folder, sourcing your system install and rebuilding the workspace:

```
cd /home/user/repo/workspace
rm -rf build devel
source /opt/ros/include/setup.bash
catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-09-26**:
Thanks @ahendrix, I've updated my question. So essentially, Qt messes up the workspace env variable, sourcing it messes up the `PATH` variable, so when I invoke `catkin_make` it can't find the command because the ROS directory is not longer in `PATH`? Is that an appropriate summary?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-09-26**:
`catkin clean` also deletes devel file, so that fits with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### TL;DR

Run `catkin clean` in the affected workspace to clear the devel folder. Open a new terminal without the messed up `PATH`, source the ROS distro, run `catkin_make`.

#### Full Explanation

@ahendrix's answer is correct, this is a more detailed explanation of what went wrong and why. While messing with Qt, I had unintentionally changed the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

As explained in the catkin [workspace mechanics](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mechanics.html) and [catkin config](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html) docs, the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` dictates how your workspace is chained and where catkin looks for dependencies. Somehow, I had changed `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and then built the workspace using Qt, so that the erroneous `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` ended up as part of the workspaces' environment variables.

A workspace with the correct environment variables (use `catkin config` to see this) should look something like this:

```
Extending:          [cached] /opt/ros/indigo
Workspace:                   /home/user/repo/workspace
```

Where the ROS distribution has been sourced first (either using `source` or by editing your .bashrc file) and *then* extended by workspace.

Because I had (somehow) set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the wrong file path, my workspace environment variables looked like this:

```
Extending:          [cached] /home/user/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64
Workspace:                   /home/user/repo/workspace
```

Which is obviously wrong. Then, by sourcing this workspace again I was effectively overwriting my `PATH` with this erroneous file path, creating a `PATH` variable that didn't include the ROS distribution (i.e. included "/home/user/Qt..." instead of "/opt/ros/indigo"). `catkin_make` is actually a tool provided in your ROS distribution, and not a built-in command like catkin clean or config. So when invoking `catkin_make`, Ubuntu searched my `PATH` for the directory containing `catkin_make`, and because the necessary directory wasn't there, gave me the "command not found" error.

To fix this, run `catkin clean` in the affected workspace, which clears the workspace devel folder. Then build the workspace again using `catkin_make` in a new terminal, being careful to only source the ROS distribution first.

If there's anything wrong with my explanation or something I should add, please let me know. Thanks to @psammut and @ahendrix for pointing me in the right direction.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1